# trace bean creation from code in a spring application

Tags: java, spring

Our spring context takes a ridiculously long time to create - like 2.5 minutes - so I want to get rid of that time and build a test such that it can never happen again.  Essentially - I want to build a junit test that looks something like

```
setup bean tracing
application.run()
for (BeanTime bean : createdBeans
    if (bean.creationTimeInMs > 100) 
        Assert.Fail(" bean " + bean.Name + " in " + bean.ownerClass 
         + " is slowing down application startup time.  Please fix.");
```

but I've found it very difficult to actually hook in and watch the bean creation - I tried making a cglib proxy around the beanfactory that gets created above - and inject my own - but it either isn't working or is being injected too late.

So - to be precise - the question is - is there any way, from code - I can trace every bean that is created and the elapsed time taken to do so?

Comment: Are you using `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`? If so extend it yourself, then log the loading

Comment: no - it's something like the annotationwebservletapplicatonContext - but the thing is - I'm running a springApplication - it creates the context itself, and I looked at the code of it and didn't see any way of injecting my own context.

Comment: Also - the reason I'm running the application instead of creating the context is when I just created that sort of context and refreshed it - it seemed to skip all my configuration files - didn't find any beans, and just didn't work at all.   I looked at springapplication, and it does _heaps_ of stuff

Comment: Enable DEBUG or TRACE logging to see what is going on and what takes al one time. I suspect (if you use JPA) that it is the setup of that.